# Spring Web MVC: How to retrieve model (passed as map) in a view?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model

When using `ModelandView` constructor with two parameters - `String viewName, Map model` - to pass multiple parameters to a *view* `JSP`, how do I then retrieve them?

If they are retrieved like map values, then what is the map name?

Let say, my *controller* code has the following:

```
    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myModel.put("1", "one");
    myModel.put("2", "two");
    return new ModelAndView("view", myModel);
```

What do I need to put into `JSP` so "**one**" and "**two**" appear on the page?

I'm using Java EE 7, Spring 3.2.4, GlassFish 4 server

**UPDATE:**

SOLVED (See the accepted answer).

> Since this post continues to receive downvotes I would like to point
>   out that I posted what I unsuccessfully tried and what actually worked
>   in my response to the accepted answer below on the same day the question was posted and answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model objects will be exposed using their keys:

```
Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myModel.put("myVar", "myValue");
return new ModelAndView("view", myModel);
```

In the JSP file:

```
...
<p>${myVar}</p>
...
```

I am not sure if it would work with your given variable names (`1` and `2`). But I would recommend to use real good names for your variable, as in your Java code.

Note that you could create the `ModelAndView` without to have to create a `Map` like this:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("view");
modelAndView.add("myVar", "myValue");
return modelAndView;
```

Comment: I used "`first`" and "`second`" as keys and it worked.  It indeed didn't work with "`1`" and "`2`".

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to put `"1"` as `model` key, you can retrieve the value like this

1. `<%out.print(request.getAttribute("1"));%>`
2. using el like this `${requestScope['1']}`

**Note that** put `"1"` as `model` key is really a bad idea.